# How to handle values that don't match entity value?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi I have made an entity called `answers` in dialogflow, this entity contains all the answers to my questions for my quiz game.

I get the questions from my database and then check to see if the given answer is correct.

```
app.intent('answer-question', (conv, {answer})=> {

  if(answer == ((conv.data.answers)[0])){
//stuff}

else{
conv.close('you lose');
}

});
```

However, this function only works when the user gets the answer correct. If the user answers the question incorrectly, then I get the following error:

```
"Question Master isn't responding right now. Try again soon."
MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set.
```

So my question is, how can i cater for the infinite selection of wrong answers a user might give?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle that in a fallback intent. A new Dialogflow agent comes with a default: https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/default-intents#default_fallback_intent

You should also consider using contexts, so the fallback intent knows that you are expecting an answer and provide a different response when an answer isn't expected.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I had tried this previously but It didn't work. The reason was that dialogflow had auto populated an 'Input Context' for the fallback intent, so it would always break since there was never any input. I removed that context and it worked fine.